# Not able to add Header in http resquest in angular 2

Tags: angular

Not able to http request header i am using following code

```javascript
let autheader = new Headers()
autheader.append("Authorization", "xyz");

this.http.get("http://localhost:8081/hello", {headers: autheader})
    .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
            // window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.headers.get("authentication")));                    
        } else if (data.status !== 200) {
            alert("error");
        }
    })
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you narrow down the problem?

Comment: Your `data.headers` is null

Comment: i am not  getting any error only thing is my header which i am setting is not getting set because of this i am not able to receive auth token (which i am setting) at back end(server).

Comment: i got the problem its caused by preflight cors request

Comment: do you have any idea is there any code in angular2 like for CORS  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";

Comment: i got the solution which i have posted below. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a little confusion here. You are adding the `authorization` header into the **Request Header**, and then you are trying to read the **Response Header**.

To your `data.headers` contain the `authentication` key you have to add it in your server.

Comment: no alexandre i am not reading response header, i am reading request header only but thing i am not able to see it, i am using developers tool in chrome to see it.

Comment: do you have any idea is there any code in angular2 like for CORS  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Could you add the request information from chrome dev tools into the question

Comment: i got the solution which i have posted above. Thank you alexandre for your help

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

*I am using angular2 in front end and spring security oauth2 in back end.*
**The problem was in server side the browser will do a preflight(CORS) request to the server with OPTION as a request method, this thing we have to handle in Server side by making a CORS filter after this in configuration part you have to add the following which will override all the other filter and will be take first and last filter.**

*code*

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableResourceServer
 public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
{
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
 }

 }
```

**The addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class) part was which i was missing**